# Passing Current URL in address bar variable to a link in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

**What I am trying to achieve is :**

1. Get Current URL Address from browser bar which will look like this `http://example.com/test/index.html?&dv1=1023faf2ee37cbbfa441eca0e1a36c`
2. Get the long ID number at the end of the URL `1023faf2ee37cbbfa441eca0e1a364`
3. Dynamically pass it into another link in the same page `http://example.org/?1023faf2ee37cbbfa441eca0e1a364` passing it as a variable to this code `onclick="nextQuestion(6, 'http://www.example/iclk/redirect.php?apxcode=042004&id=eT9HmN9XD3xMgT8nKUj0KRjM‌​IWuXeTj0KN2-0N&dv1={id}');"` repacing the last part `id`.

I need to do this using **jquery** or **javascript** NO PHP

Comment: How have you done so far? Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following function to get the part I need from the link

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}


var foo = getQueryVariable("dv1");
```

Comment: Why did you accept this as the answer to your question? It's just partially answering it.

Answer (score 2):

I completely reworked this answer. I think I now understood your problem.

Generally spoken it's a bad idea to inline event handlers. You should separate structure and behaviour. You can easily do this by binding the handlers inside your javascript, instead of in your markup.

To do this you just have to

1. Remove the `onclick` from the button, add an identifier (`question`)

   ```
   <a class="btn rollover question">click me</a>
   ```
2. Then you can do

   ```
   $('.question').click(function() {
       var id = getQueryVariable("dv1");
       nextQuestion(6, 'http://www.example/iclk/redirect.php?apxcode=042004&id=eT9HmN9XD3xMgT8nKUj0KRjM‌​IWuXeTj0KN2-0N&dv1=' + id);
   });
   ```

You might want to check the full example in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12u69afs/2/). It's not working because the fiddle runs inside an iframe, but as soon as you copy it to your project, it'll work.

Oh and one last thing: You might want to use a library to get parameters from the url. The safest, easiest & most reliable way of doing stuff is to use libraries. In your case you might want to try [simple-query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-query-string).

Comment: thanks for you answer mark, after I got the id I need to be able to put inside a custom href link like <a href="example.com/test/link/id" ></a>

Comment: Means there's no clear identifier, like an id or a class? You can aswell query by an href, like so: `$('a[href="example.com/test/link/id"]')` or via reg ex, if you, for example, just know the last part of the link (like in your example the `id`): `$("a[href$='id']")`

Comment: No. my idea is I want to pass the `id` as a variable to be in the middle of another code like this `<a class="btn rollover" onclick="nextQuestion(6, 'http://www.example/iclk/redirect.php?apxcode=042004&id=eT9HmN9XD3xMgT8nKUj0KRjMIWuXeTj0KN2-0N&dv1={id}');">` the method you mentioned won't' work as I don't want an href I want a variable to be passed in the onclick action above.